# How to get values from google marker in angular 2

Tags: angular

I am using angular 2 RC?

How to get `LatLng` from google marker in angular 2

How to set Marker center when user is dragging in angular 2?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
<sebm-google-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng">
    <sebm-google-map-marker id="marker" [latitude]="lat" [markerDraggable]="true" (dragEnd)="pos($event)"
        [longitude]="lng" [label]="'V'" (markerClick)="mehod()">
</sebm-google-map-marker>
</sebm-google-map>
```

Now in map.component.ts

```
    pos(event){
        this.zone.run(() => {
            this.lat = event.coords.lat;
            this.lng = event.coords.lng;
        });
    }
```

Comment: can u describe . because when i am writing new google.maps.Marker in that line only i am getting error .Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you check that if your google obj is defined or not. Or you can share your code so that i can have a look.

Comment: see google docs for map api. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers

Comment: can u tell me how to share my code.if u don't mind i am new to this

Comment: either you can create a Plunker or share your map code here. paste only where you have initialised the map and where markers are being generated.

Comment: [link ](http://plnkr.co/edit/YbiMDuQxBN5ea8FFFFf1?p=preview  )
if plunker link is troubling plz create new plunker

Comment: how to get full address from latlng in angular 2

Comment: getDetailsByGeometry(lat,lng){
     let geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
     geocoder.geocode({'latLng': new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng)}, function (results, status) {
   console.log(results[0].address_components);
     });
 }